# How to return a value on Clojure try/catch

Tags: clojure, exception

I've a function in Clojure where I want to return true when an exception occurs, just like the code below;

```
    (try
        (code)
    (catch Exception e true)))
```

However the approach above gives me the following error:

> ClassCastException java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn  signal.message/read? (message.clj:12)

It only works if a put a function instead:

```
    (try
        (code)
    (catch Exception e (= 1 1)))
```

Any way to return a value on Clojure catch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Test your `catch` using:

```
(try
  (throw (RuntimeException.))
  (catch Exception e true)))
```

Running this code would return `true`.

Answer (score 1):

What you've written in your question is exactly right: that try/catch as written returns true if `(code)` throws an exception. The problem is elsewhere: either the code around this try/catch has too many parentheses, or you have pasted code that does not match the real code you are running.